# Display value in ButtonRow

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

Is it possible to display a value in a `ButtonRow` using the `Eureka` library?

I tried this but it's not working ("Row value" is not displayed):

```
<<< ButtonRow("Rows") {
      $0.title = "Row title"
      $0.value = "Row value"
    }
```

What I'd like to have is a row displaying an information. When the user touches the row, another `ViewController` would be displayed. He could modify the information in this `Viewcontroller` and then press Save. Then the row would display the newly saved information.

Comment: I guess I could use a LabelRow (instead of the ButtonRow) and then segue to my other `ViewController` when the event onCellSelection occurs...

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand you want to go to another ViewController from a ButtonRow ??

I think you'd be better off using a PushRow which does exactly what you want, something like this :

```
<<< PushRow("Rows") {
          $0.title = "Row title"
          $0.value = "Row value"
          $0.options = ["Row value","Row value2","Row value3"]
        }
```

Or if you want more options, you could always use a ButtonRow to send to another ViewController, but that's more complicated. You'll have to :

1. Create the new ViewController in Storyboard,
2. Create a new class that defines this new ViewController, like :

> class ViewController2: FormViewController { }

3. add segues to present the new ViewController from the starting point.
4. reference segues in your code with the button row (example taken from the eureka Example app)

   ```
     <<< ButtonRow("Rows") { 
    $0.title = $0.tag 
    $0.presentationMode = .SegueName (segueName: "ViewController2Segue", completionCallback: nil)}
   ```

either way would work, but the button row would be much more complicated.

Hope that helps